# Background Images - Making a full width image within a container

Tags: css, html, background-image, containers

I need to put HTML content within a page template. The section I have been given is within a Div container defining the size I have to work with. The CSS for the template defines margins of 17.5% left and right meaning I have 65% in the centre to input my content. This is ok for a majority of the content I need to include except the background image that needs to be full width (100%). I can attach a style sheet with my content however if I change the .wrapper element in my css it causes issues with the rest of the page. I also have to change the background image on a page by page basis so have to include the image path in the HTML and not in the CSS.

What I have so far is

HTML:

```
 <div class="pageBackground">
        <img src="img/festival-background.jpg">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.pageBackground {
position: relative;
```

}

```
.pageBackground img {
width: 100%;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size:cover;
```

}

What would be a correct way to make my background image 100% of the page rather then container and behind the rest of my content?

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: if it is a child it will be 100% of it's parent. Try making the parent 100% of the page.

Comment: The problem is the parent is .wrapper in the templates css which I cannot really edit. Is there a way to "break" the parents rules?

Comment: if you can't edit the 'wrapper' parent, does that mean you can only access your specific div?

Comment: Pretty much. I can give the 3rd party a style sheet to attach but they are not keen on letting me touch their existing CSS. Basically I have an area within their template to add my content but as I say the area I have is wrapped in a Div with the class "wrapper" which is styled left and right margin at 17.5% but my background must be full page! (I hope that makes sense!)

Comment: Change .wrapper to be full width + height then add a new DIV to replace the original .wrapper DIV with the old 17.5% margins. the .wrapper DIV will probably need to be positioned absolutely with the appropriate z-index. the new DIV will be positioned relatively with a higher z-index. Give that a go and see if it works for you.

Comment: @BillyMoat He can't access .wrapper, which is the problem.

Comment: @TylerH - I may have read it wrong. I thought he could add css rules which could affect .wrapper but not access the .wrapper html?

Comment: @BillyMoat See OP's first comment above. It's a template which he cannot edit. I don't know the specifics other than that.

Comment: I can't edit the .wrapper css or html, but I can add my own style sheet and adding .wrapper to that overrides the original, but screws up the rest of the template page

Comment: @user3375160 I've updated my answer a bit. See if it now solves your problem?

Answer (score 6):

This is entirely possible using the same techniques as detailed in this [**Q/A**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845451/css-make-colours-go-off-to-sides).

Essentially, using no additional HTML, we use an absolutely positioned pseudo-element as the background to the required section/div.

```
.extra {
    position: relative;    
}

.extra::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1000-250-5.jpg);
    background-size: cover ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 65%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
section {
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
.extra {
  position: relative;
}
.extra::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/image_output/abstract-q-c-100-100-1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section></section>
  <section class="extra"></section>
  <section></section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS, add the background image to the body property and then put the rest of your site in an entire container div, within which all other properties will reside.

HTML:

```
 <body>
   <div class="entireSite">
     Site content goes here.
   </div>
 </body>
```

CSS:

```
.body {
   background-image:url("img/festival-background.jpg");
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size:cover;
}

.entireSite {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: I need to use different backgrounds on different pages so I can't really put the image path in the CSS. Also I pretty much can only input HTML between the Div container I have access to and give a 3rd party a style sheet to attach so I can't really edit the main CSS file.

Comment: @user3375160 if you don't have access to the main CSS file, and you need this to be a background image, then I think you are out of luck. You could, however, work as if your div container is the `<body>` of the site, and put all your content in a div inside your div container (except for the background image). You can use padding or negative margins. With `overflow: visible;`, your image will be larger than the div, but whether it will work as the background image for the whole `<body>` or not is another question. It's difficult to know without access to the whole HTML/CSS.

Comment: Also by margin I actually mean padding-left and padding-right of 17.5%. Sorry for any confusion, brain's fried!

Comment: If the parent uses `padding` instead of `margin`, try setting your `div` to have `position: absolute;`. This should ignore the padding of the parent container.

Comment: @TylerH I think this last comment is the solution. With `z-index :-1` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you have that kind of permission, but you could put img outside that div, and set them both on position absolute.

```
<img src="asdf>
<div class="wrapper">
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
width: 65%;
background-color: transparent;
height: 300px;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -150px;
margin-left: -32.5%;
}

img {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background-color: gray;

}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GDW2R/)